# lxml cleaner with a custom tag?

Tags: python, xss, lxml

I want to use lxml cleaner to get rid of all html, but then a regex to autolink something:

```
[ABC] -> <a href="bah bah bah">ABC</a>
```

what is the right way to handle this without xss and such?

Comment: what do you mean by "autolink something"? I don't understand [ABC] -> ABC

Comment: thx, sry, it got stripped away, should be me clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using markdown with inline HTML disabled would be suitable?  The python [markdown](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown/) module is quite mature.

Check out the "safe mode" section in the [docs](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Using_as_a_Module#title) for more info on stripping out inline HTML.

Depending on what you want, something like [py-wikimarkup](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-wikimarkup) may be more appropriate.

Using a custom regexp is probably not a great idea, because

- you'll have to explain the rules to people who might already be familiar with markdown/WikiText
- you'll have to provide a way to escape text, e.g. for people who really want to write `[ABC]`
- you'll have to fix any bugs, including security issues